# Example of finite ring which is not a Bézout ring

Tags: ring-theory

A *left* (or *right*) *Bézout ring* is a ring in which any two elements generate a principal left (resp. right) ideal. Assume that we have a *finite* ring *R*. Does there exist some classification theorem (necessary and sufficient condition for a finite ring to be a Bézout ring other than just formulating the above definition)?
Is the ring of matrices $M_{n \times n}(q)$  over the Galois field $GF(q)$ a Bézout ring and how do you prove that. Are there examples of finite rings (commutative or not) which are not Bézout rings? Are there examples of finite *local* rings (commutative or not) that are not Bézout rings?

Comment: If you restrict to *finite* rings, I am surprised you talk about Bézout rings as opposed to PIDs, which in this case is the same but more common (I think).

Comment: You are right, I can reformulate my questions for PIR's (not necessarily PID's) in the case of finite rings.

Comment: One definition, one assumption and four questions.  Voting to close as "too broad."  As for the examples, [here is a finite local commutative nonBezout ring](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/23/) and here are at least four [nonBezout finite rings](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=43&L=67l).

Answer (score 1):

*Getting this out of unanswered-limbo*

---

> Is the ring of matrices $_{×}()$
> over the Galois field $()$
> a Bézout ring and how do you prove that.

Yes it is. Every right ideal and every left ideal are principal, because they are all summands and therefore generated by an idempotent.

> Are there examples of finite rings (commutative or not) which are not Bézout rings?

Yes, like $F_2[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ for the field of two elements $F_2$, and also the trivial extension of $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$ by itself.

> Are there examples of finite local rings (commutative or not) that are not Bézout rings?

Both rings mentioned above are local.

Comment: [DaRT query for commutative examples](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=43&H=23&L=67l).